# Extreme Adaptation

Tags: science-in-society, adaptability

I'm writing a novel, and it has a lot to do with genetic experimentation. One of my characters has the ability of Reactive Evolution. But I have no idea how to scientifically explain that. How is Reactive Evolution scientifically explained?
The character has gone through some genetic experiments, where the scientists put several teens under tests to see if they evolved to survive. What I want to do is have his body be able to adapt whenever it is put under attack. But I'm not sure how to explain how his body can adapt, then restore itself back to its original state.
 If this question has problems, then please note them and try to improve it.

Comment: Hi LilliScroft, and welcome to Worldbuilding! This sounds like a cool novel, but we’ll need a little bit more information to answer your question. Are you trying to brainstorm ideas for what a “reactive evolution” superpower would do? Or do you already have something in mind and are hoping to justify it with some evolutionary biology?

Comment: Please not that (scientifically speaking) evolution is adaption to long-lasting external factors *over multiple generations*, whereas the power you are describing is (rapid) adaption of a single organism to individual cues. Additionally it would be good if you can add information about the technology level of the experiments (current day, future , ...) as well the how science based answers should be (from plausible to backed by hard science).

Comment: *"the scientists had put several teens under tests to see if they evolved to survive"* Individuals don't evolve; populations do. If you want to have a scientifically plausible explanation for something, you really need to start with something that makes sense scientifically.

Comment: You don't necessarily explain it, you sidestep it as something that's not understood.  If that seems like a cheat keep in mind you will not find a way to explain something like this scientifically.  You are describing something like superhero characters who are normal one minute and e.g. have diamond skin the next.  So "reactive evolution" is just "mutant power" or "super power" and just as impossible to provide a real explanation for.

Comment: Individuals don't evolve.  Evolution takes place at the species level, and works by killing off the less fit individuals.  What you seem to want here is an individual with extreme ADAPTABILITY.

Comment: The Simpsons explored this concept back in 1993: [It's the Curies, we must flee!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx5tuyB70DE). Cool....

Comment: @jamesqf There's an X-Men character called Darwin with this exact same ability, and it's even referred to as "reactive evolution". I have a feeling that's where OP got the power and the name from, now they just need an explanation of how it would work. X-Men is very hand-wavey in that regard.

Comment: @F1Krazy: According to Google, "X-men" is a comic book series.  Perhaps not the best of sources for information on evolutionary biology :-)

Answer (score 3):

One kind of simple, slightly handwavy way is if your character can control the rate any his cells multiply and they rate they mutate at. He can accelerate the whole life cycle of a particular group of cells, so they split and die of at a very high speed. He can induce them to have a higher mutation rate and more variance. Most of those new cells will be useless or die off. Some of the cells will be better and have the properties he needs.

The second part of his ability would be to somehow "remember" the cell mutations and be able to cause them at will after having experienced and felt them. Perhaps he can learn how mutations feel and use that feeling to guide the cells towards it.

This way he can take a lighter and burn his skin, induce it to multiply and heal very quickly and keep burning it so that more and more cells with fire resistant mutations will appear. Since any newly-evolved fire resistant cells will take longer to burn and have a higher chance of multiplying than non-fire-resistant ones that die quickly, eventually they will all be replaced by fire resistant cells.

If he can memorize the feeling of those cells, he can make his body grow them and become fire resistant. He can then repeat the same with other forms of damage, like frostbite, blunt trauma, acids, irritants, poisons, etc.

Comment: answer is correct. The superpower that OP wants is not "evolution", it is "metamorphosis" or metabolism, which the character controls, or which is triggered by environmental cues. 

E.g. if is cold, normal human skin develops goosebumps. The character's skin actually grows more hair, in a matte of minutes.

Comment: Well that's a very different bag of fish. We have a shapeshifter on our hands in your case.

Comment: Or, hmm, can still work. If he learns to make his cells grow hair or scales or whatever, then remembers that, later he can grow them on demand really.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your reactive evolution, in its current form, violates a commonsense rule which I call "conservation of information".  What is the source of the knowledge of which specific genetic changes will allow for survival in any given situation?

In the real world, evolution is just a side effect of mutation on a massive scale.  Lifeforms change in random ways, some of which help survive a current environmental change while others hurt that same survival effort.  Individuals are not helped by evolution because their mutations are not guaranteed to be situation-ally advantageous.  Large populations slowly benefit from evolution as long as you ignore the massive death tolls suffered along the way.

For your super powered individual to benefit from evolution, all of their mutations have to be situation-ally beneficial.  For that to happen, some source of knowledge has to be controlling the process.

I would suggest the following...

In the eons before humanity climbed down from the trees, the Zookeeper AI traveled the galaxy, studying life in all its forms and cataloging the myriad ways that life can adapt to almost any challenge.  During its journey, it managed its own evolution carefully, moving slowly from the silicon of its original host, to photon-ic crystals, and eventually into the carbon-based viral form in which it currently abides.  In its' study of life, it learned that life itself is the safest and most resilient host for its vast intelligence.  It evolved into a virus which can take over the mutagen-ic process of its host, applying evolution intelligently to help both of them to survive.

It isn't your super hero who has the power to reactive-ly evolve, it is the Zookeeper AI virus which has chosen (at least for now) to live inside of him

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your idea!